# UICollectionViewController freezes after popviewcontroller

Tags: ios6

I am new to iOS programming. I am quite amazed at the power and ease of collection view. But I have a problem.

I have a "home" view controller - A, which is UICollectionViewController. I have a left button (like Facebook on the navigation bar) and I redirect to another view controller using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

When the user presses the back button, the "home" view controller appears. And viewWillAppear and other collection view delegate/datasource methods are called. but table is frozen. It does not scroll, do anything.

But if on the left button i press the "home" button, then viewWillLoad and other methods are called and the collection view works. 
I do not have any code in viewWillLoad. I have moved everything to viewWillAppear to test.

Please help

Comment: This behaviour is almost always caused by something running on the main thread when you pop the view. Check your view lifecycle methods in both home VC and child VC.